# cambiar nombre de variable en PHP de forma dinámica

Tags: php

Buenas,

Tengo un pequeño bucle `foreach` el cual recorre un array asociativo, os pongo el código:

```
        $paises = ['espanya' => "€", 'usa' => "$", 'brasil' => "R$", 'canada' => "C$", 'colombia' => "COP", 'hongkong' => "HK$", 'hungria' => "HUF", 'rusia' => "R$", 'singapur' => "S$", 'sudafrica' => "ZAR", 'mexico' => "MXN", 'argentina' => "ARS"];
        $moneda_a_mostrar = "espanya";

        foreach ($paises as $pais => $moneda) {

            echo "<div class='cajita'>";
                echo "<img class='bandera' src='imagenes/Banderas/" . $pais . ".png'/>";

    //Comprueba si el valor es nulo, si lo es muestra en pantalla el valor "N/A".
    //Si el juego es gratuito el valor es 123456 y muestra Free en pantalla.

                    if ($post["$pais"] == 0.00) {
                        echo  "<p class='nodisponible'>N/A</p>";
                    }

                    if ($post["$pais"] == 123456.00) {
                        echo "<p class='gratis'> Free</p>";
                    }

                    if ($post["$pais"] == 666) {
                        echo "<p class='bundle'>Only with bundle</p>";
                    }

                    if ($post["$pais"] != 0.00 AND $post["$pais"] != 123456.00 AND $post["$pais"] != 666) {
                        echo "<p class='mitad'>" . number_format($post["$pais"],2,'.',',') . $moneda . "</p>";
                    }

    //Comprueba si el valor no es nulo, si lo es no se muestra en pantalla la flecha.


                    if ($post["$pais"] != 0.00 AND $post["$pais"] != 123456.00 AND $post["$pais"] != 666) {
                        echo "<i class='fa fa-long-arrow-right' aria-hidden='true'></i>";
                    }

    // Si el número no es nulo, entonces hace una comprobación para saber si el valor es el mínimo o no.-->



                    $precio_usa = number_format($post["$pais"] * $divisa_usa,2,'.','');

                    if ($post["$pais"] != 0.00) {
                        if ($post["$pais"] != 123456.00 AND $post['usa'] != 666){
                            if (number_format($post["$pais"] * $divisa_usa,2,'.','') == $valor_minimo) {
                                echo "<p class='menor'>" . $precio_usa = number_format($post["$pais"] * $divisa_usa,2,'.','')  .  $moneda . "</p>";
                            } else {
                                echo "<p class='mitad2'>" . $precio_usa = number_format($post["$pais"] * $divisa_usa,2,'.','')  . $moneda . "</p>";
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    echo "</div>";
```

El problema que no encuentro cómo resolverlo, es que la variable `$divisa_usa` quiero que cambie el nombre, la última parte, para que cada vez que lo recorre sea por ejemplo `$divisa_espanya`, sin embargo no consigo hacer que la variable modifique el nombre. Tan sólo quiero que la última parte de la variable sea agregada por el nombre del país del array asociativo. ¿Es eso posible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes declarar una variable con el nombre que quieras usar, por ejemplo

```
$divisa_del_pais = 'divisa_'.$pais
```

Esto evidentemente te va a dar que en cada each la variable `$divisa_del_pais` va a valer por ejemplo en la primera iteración `'divisa_espanya'`, ahora bien para sacar el valor de una variable con texto basta con usar el `$$` antes de la variable a declarar, es decir;

```
$$divisa_del_pais
```

Por lo que tu código quedaría

```
 $divisa_del_pais = 'divisa_'.$pais
$precio_usa = number_format($post["$pais"] * $$divisa_del_pais,2,'.','');
```

Por poner un ejemplo, si te quedaron dudas puedes echarle un ojo a la documentación de variables variables (nombre redundante) en php

http://php.net/manual/es/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! No sabía que podía poner dos veces `$$`. Resuelto el problema pues.